# angular ng-message animation not work properly

Tags: angularjs, animation, ng-animate

i want to apply animation on ng-message error.for this i see angular documentation for animation but unable to use it properly. I required animation on error when it active.and also disappear with animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at-last here is the solution of my problem

> .messages.ng-active{
>       transition:1s linear all;
>       opacity:1;
>
> }
>
> .messages.ng-inactive{
>       transition:1s linear all;
>       opacity:0; } .massege.ng-leave {
>       transition:0.5s linear all;
>
> } .massege.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
>
> ```
> opacity:0; }
> ```

in syntax of ng-messages there are one parent and three , four child 
so for this we have to apply animation on parent child both :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation carefully of angular

[ngMessage documentaion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages)

and there is a example of angular ng-message animation.

[example of angular ng-message animation](http://embed.plnkr.co/oPrpTmhWCeR8zz2iiYSf/preview)